# Can pdb files be added to a nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget, pdb-files

We are building packages to a local nuget gallary, using azure pipelines (YAML build files) to build the packages and add them to our gallary

The executables are packaged from GeneratePackageOnBuild instruction in the csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
<Version>5.0.4</Version>
```

Is it possible to add pdb files to the package as well, so they are distributed with our services which use the package?

The purpose would be two things:

1. Get line numbers in stack-traces
2. Being able to debug in to library code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a "symbol package", it will create another file with a `.snupkg` extension that you can also upload to your registry.

Simply add this to your .csproj file to automatcily create one when packaging the project.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
</PropertyGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg

You might also be interested in SourceLink to get the best experience when debugging.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/sourcelink

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is what I was looking for. Our Azure pipeline though is not pushing the snuget to our gallary. We are pushing with the azure task NuGetPublisher@0 . Do you know how to ensure the snuget is also pushed to our gallary ?

Comment: Sorry, I've only uploaded snupkg-packages through the nuget.org interface, never through a CI-job :/

Comment: Thanks. I found out that our Gallary (JFrog / Artifactory) does not support symbol nuget packages. So I am kind of stuck right now